# Determine and classify all equilibrium points of this non-linear DE

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> Consider the DE  $\begin{cases}
> \dot{x}=-2x(x-1)(2x-1)\\
> \dot{y}=-2y
> \end{cases}$. Determine all equilibrium points and classify these. Choose between a saddle point, (in)stable nod, center or a (in)stable spiral.

I have found $(0,0), (1,0), (\frac{1}{2},0)$ to be the equilibrium points of the system, but I am stuck at classifying them.

To classify them, I determined the following Jacobian matrix:
$$J=\begin{bmatrix}-12x^{2}+12x-2 & 0\\
0 & -2
\end{bmatrix}$$.

For $(0,0)$, I found:

$$J_{(0,0)}=\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 0\\
0 & -2
\end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow\lambda=\begin{vmatrix}-2-\lambda & 0\\
0 & -2-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}
=(-2-\lambda)(-2-\lambda)=0
\iff\lambda_{1,2}=-2$$

The corresponding eigenvectors are:
$v_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\
0
\end{bmatrix},\,v_{2}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$

Which are linearly independent, so the corresponding phase portrait is a stable star. However, this option wasn't listed in the question, so I must have made a mistake. Could anyone give me a hint here?

Comment: That is a type of stable node.